# SAS store the character representation on a date in a macro variable

Tags: date, character, sas, sas-macro

I have a table looking like this

```
DATE
01FEB2001
02FEB2001
...
```

After loading this table I create macro-variables like

```
data _null_;
    set TBL end=eof;    
    call symput('dtBourse'||left(_N_),DATE);
run;
```

My problem is that the `dtBourse1,dtBourse2` macro variables are worth `17433...` (their underlying integer value as a date is stored as an integer)

How can I make sure the macro-variable are characters `"01FEB2001","02FEB2001"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the VVALUE function, which returns the formatted value

```
call symput('dtBourse'||left(_N_),vvalue(DATE));
```